# How do I call the functions: def(dot) and def(dice) from def(main)?

Tags: python, function, graphics

I'm having trouble calling the top two functions from the third(main) function. I believe I have the coding correct(ignore the sizes and x,y coordinates) to display a the five side of a di but can't seem to figure out how to call the functions.

main objective is to display the five side of the di.

```
def dot(c,d):
 #draw each dot 
 circDot1 = Circle(Point(50, 50), 5).setFill('black')
 circDot1.draw(win)
 circDot3 = Circle(Point(50, 100), 5).setFill('black')
 circDot3.draw(win)
 circDot5 = Circle(Point(100, 50), 5).setFill('black')
 circDot5.draw(win)
 circDot7 = Circle(Point(100, 100), 5).setFill('black')
 circDot7.draw(win)
 circDot4 = Circle(Point(75, 75), 5).setFill('black')
 circDot4.draw(win)

def dice(a,b):

 #build the dice
 rectDice = Rectangle(Point(115, 115), Point(275,275))
 rectDice.setFill('pink')
 rectDice.setOutline('pink')
 rectDice.draw(win)


def main():
 # Create window, call dice function
 win = GraphWin("Dice", 400, 400)
 win.setBackground("cyan")
 dice("a","b")
```

Comment: add `print()` in functions to see if they are executed.

Comment: do you get error when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you try adding `.show()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems:

You don't execute `main()` to run program but maybe you didn't add this only in question.

---

`win` is local variable and functions don't have access to them. You should see it in error message as `NameError: name 'win' is not defined` in `rectDice.draw(win)`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 28, in main
    dice("a","b")
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 21, in dice
    rectDice.draw(win)
NameError: name 'win' is not defined
```

You may add `win` as argument

```
def dice(win, a, b):
    #build the dice
    rectDice = Rectangle(Point(115, 115), Point(275,275))
    rectDice.setFill('pink')
    rectDice.setOutline('pink')
    rectDice.draw(win)

def main():
    # Create window, call dice function
    win = GraphWin("Dice", 400, 400)
    win.setBackground("cyan")
    dice(win, "a","b")
```

or you would have to assign window to global variable - using `global` in `main()`

```
def dice(a, b):
    #build the dice
    rectDice = Rectangle(Point(115, 115), Point(275,275))
    rectDice.setFill('pink')
    rectDice.setOutline('pink')
    rectDice.draw(win)

def main():
    global win

    # Create window, call dice function
    win = GraphWin("Dice", 400, 400)
    win.setBackground("cyan")
    dice("a", "b")
```

The same problem is in `dot()`

---

In `dot()` you have other problem. You have to use `setFill()` in next line

```
circDot1 = Circle(Point(50, 50), 5)
circDot1.setFill('black')
circDot1.draw(win)
```

---

Full code:

```
from graphics import *

def dot(win, c, d):
    #draw each dot 
    circDot1 = Circle(Point(50, 50), 5)
    circDot1.setFill('black')
    circDot1.draw(win)

    circDot3 = Circle(Point(50, 100), 5)
    circDot3.setFill('black')
    circDot3.draw(win)

    circDot5 = Circle(Point(100, 50), 5)
    circDot5.setFill('black')
    circDot5.draw(win)

    circDot7 = Circle(Point(100, 100), 5)
    circDot7.setFill('black')
    circDot7.draw(win)

    circDot4 = Circle(Point(75, 75), 5)
    circDot4.setFill('black')
    circDot4.draw(win)

def dice(win, a, b):
    #build the dice
    rectDice = Rectangle(Point(115, 115), Point(275,275))
    rectDice.setFill('pink')
    rectDice.setOutline('pink')
    rectDice.draw(win)


def main():
    # Create window, call dice function
    win = GraphWin("Dice", 400, 400)
    win.setBackground("cyan")
    dice(win, "a", "b")
    dot(win, "c", "d")

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I didn't add main() because I was prompted to keep the code short, only showing where the issue is.

Comment: it is good to keep code short, but it is also good to create minimal working code - with `main()` and `import` - so we can easily copy code and run it to see problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think your main() function is not even called too.

try to use this:

```
def main():
 # Create window, call dice function
 win = GraphWin("Dice", 400, 400)
 win.setBackground("cyan")
 dice("a","b")

if __name__== "__main__":
 main()
```

Reference: [this link](https://www.guru99.com/learn-python-main-function-with-examples-understand-main.html)